# Can I safely cast a &char[] to char**?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Having the following code:

```
char data[2048];
```

And a function declared like this:

```
int f(char** data);
```

Can I safely call it like this:

```
f((char**)&data);
```

If I just use &data, the compiler issue the following warning:

```
warning C4047: 'function' : 'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[2048]'
```

Comment: Indeed. That is not C array syntax.

Comment: Yes it's C, compiled with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed typed the code. Edited.

Comment: ** in multiple indirection this means the function accepts a pointer that is a pointer to another. So you hava to declare two pointers like this- char *a=data; char **b=a; than you can pass b like this f(b);

Comment: Side note: The values of `data` and `&data` are necessarily identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot.

`data` is an array. `&data` is a **pointer to an array**. It is not a pointer to a pointer. Despite the fact that `data` *decays* to a pointer in multiple contexts, it is not itself a pointer - taking the address gives you the address of the array.

If you want a pointer to a pointer to the array, you might try something like this:

```
char *pdata = data; // data decays to a pointer here
                    // (a pointer to the first element of the array)
f(&pdata);          // Now &pdata is of type char ** (pointer to a pointer).
```

though, of course, what you actually need will depend on what your usecase is.

Comment: Isn't this the same than doing the cast (char**)&data ?

Comment: `data` is an array. `pdata` is a pointer. While `data` *decays* to a pointer in multiple contexts, it is not itself a pointer - taking the address gives you the address of the array.

Comment: But what's the difference with (char**)&data except that you declare a variable ?

Comment: `data` and `pdata` are different! `data` **is** an array. Taking its address gives you something different than taking the **address** of `pdata`. Consider this: how does `int x = 0; &x` differ from `&0`? (Hint: the "only" difference is that I declare a variable).

Comment: This code does however rely on that the person who implemented the function is confused about how arrays and pointers work. I would not assume that. Rare as it may be, they might actually know the difference between a pointer-to-pointer, a pointer to an array and a pointer to the first element of the array. None of which are compatible with each other.

Comment: @nneonneo Ok it's more clear. Doing *data inside the function would try to change "the array" and makes no sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Lundin: There's a perfectly good reason to do `f(&pdata)`; like `strtol`, an API user might want to have the pointer updated upon return from the function.

Comment: That's my use case nneoneo, but in my context I can't use malloc, that's why I only use statically allocated arrays :-)

Comment: @nneonneo But it that case you aren't passing an array, but a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer-to-pointer is not an array, nor is it a pointer to an array, nor should it be used to point at an array. Except for the special case where it can be used to point at the first item of an array of pointers, which is not the case here.

A function `int f(char** data);` cannot accept a `char data[2048];` array as parameter. Either the array type needs to be changed, or the function needs to be rewritten.

Correct function alternatives would be:

```
int f (char* data);
int f (char data[2048]); // completely equivalent to char* data
int f (char (*data)[2048]); // array pointer, would require to pass the address of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this more detailed example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c):

> While an array name may decay into a pointer, the address of the array does not decay into a pointer to a pointer. And why should it? What sense does it make to treat an array so?
>
> Pointers to pointers are sometimes passed to modify the pointers (simple pointer arguments don't work here because C passes by value, which would only allow to modify what's pointed, not the pointer itself). Here's some imaginary code (won't compile):

```
void test(int** p)
{
    *p = malloc ... /* retarget '*p' */
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5};
    int* ptr;

    /* Fine!
    ** test will retarget ptr, and its new value
    ** will appear after this call.
    */
    test(&ptr);

    /* Makes no sense!
    ** You cannot retarget 'arr', since it's a
    ** constant label created by the compiler.
    */
    test(&arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this relevant? The OP has a statically allocated array in main().

Comment: As you can read in the very code you posted, passing a static array to that test function makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

```
char data[2048];
char *a=&data[0];
char **b=&a;
f(b);
```